# AcceptsReturn does not work on Silverlight RichTexBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, richtextbox

I am using **RichTextBox** in **Silverlight** 5. The control loses focus on Enter! I have tried changing **AcceptsReturn** but yet the cursor does not go to the new line.

Comment: Try setting  TextWrapping="Wrap"

Comment: I've already selected this option but no change :(